# Is it possible to find tmux sockets currently in use?

Tags: tmux

I am trying to get a list of tmux sockets that are currently being used but the best solution I've come up with so far is to check in /tmp/tmux* or TMPDIR.

As far as I can tell tmux keeps these sockets around for some amount of time even if no current tmux session is using them.

As such I was hoping there was something similar to tmux list-sessions, but for sockets, that would give me all the sockets that are currently being used. I couldn't seem to find one in the man page and if there was one I didn't properly understand that listing sockets was its purpose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To list all sockets used by `tmux` you can use `lsof`:

```
lsof -U | grep '^tmux'
```

Use `sudo` if the inquirer doesn't own the process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the tmux sockets are located at /tmp, which is where they wil be by default, To list all the sockets,

lsof | grep tmp/tmux