# Is it possible to find the name of the current socket in tmux?

Tags: tmux

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333291/is-it-possible-to-find-tmux-sockets-currently-in-use).

Suppose I am inside a tmux session, and I want to print the name of the **current socket** in use. How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The info about the current server socket is stored in `TMUX` environment variable (along with some other things that I'm not sure what they are). Socket path is in the first field in a comma separated string.

Here's a one liner to get it:

```
echo $TMUX | cut -f1 -d','
```